# How to get if the timestamp is older than a day if I have timestamps with timezones?

Tags: php, date, timezone

I have timestamps with timezone, maybe in this format: `Weekday, d Month yyyy H:i:s +timezone` for example: `Fri, 28 Feb 2020 19:18:26 +010` or `Sat, 29 Feb 2020 21:57:00 +010` How can I get if it is older than a day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the timezone from your date using `preg_match` e.g.

```
$tz = preg_match('/([+-]\d+)$/', $datestr, $m) ? $m[0] : '';
```

and then create `DateTime` objects from your date string and the current time, adjusted for the timezone. If we then subtract one day from the current time and compare the two dates we can determine if the date is more than one day ago:

```
$datestr = 'Fri, 28 Feb 2020 19:18:26 +010';
$date = new DateTime($datestr);
$tz = preg_match('/([+-]\d+)$/', $datestr, $m) ? $m[0] : '';
$now = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s ' . $tz));
$now->modify('-1 day');
if ($now > $date) {
    echo "$datestr is more than 1 day ago\n";
}
```

Output (as of March 1st):

```
Fri, 28 Feb 2020 19:18:26 +010 is more than 1 day ago
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/SFPW6)

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this:
`date('d.m.Y',strtotime("-1 days"));`

Comment: this is cool but how can i get if this date is older than 1 day for example?

Comment: then write the number of days in brackets like this: `echo date('d.m.Y',strtotime("-30 days"));`. The output will be **31.01.2020** (if date today is 01.03.2020)